# Exception in setting up EMGU library in C#

Tags: c#, .net, visual-c#-express-2010, emgucv

I am trying to setup EMGU library for my C# project. I am following this link http://file.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Setting_up_EMGU_C_Sharp.

I am stuck in: **x64 Architecture and the EMGU.CV.Invoke Exception** step. I am using Visual C# 2010 Express edition and the platform target is not showing x64 option. I tried to check the Show Advanced build Configurations and then Run my project but it is throwing Type Initialization Error with Inner Exception: **"Unable to load DLL 'opencv_core242': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E)"**. But according to the above link it should throw error with ‘InnerException’ "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format....”.

Exception is thrown in following line.

```
cap = new Capture(0);
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

Just create a directory named "x64" in debug\ and copy opencv_xxx.dll inside this "x64" folder.

Answer (score 0):

It looks more like that the opencv dll's cannot be found. They are looked-up at runtime. Can you check that the **opencv_core242.dll** file is present in the BIN\Debug folder ? If I remember it should be side-by-side with the Emgu dll's files.

You have to include the OpenCV dll's and assure that they are copied to the output directory. If you are using x64 version of EmguCV than you will need also x64 version of opencv.

I have a [testing project on github](https://github.com/hoonzis/Silverlight-Face-Recognition), which uses 32bit dll binaries of DLL. I remember that I awas forced to create another version with the x64 version of DLL in order to be able to deploy to Azure (which runs only x64).

Comment: I have included opencv_core242.dll in the bin/Debug folder and also in my project as mentioned in the link above. What i am unable to do is to configure my project to work on x64 platform.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you describe is no longer related to Emgu.Cv.

Try the following link, this might solve your problem:

[MSDN Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/Vsexpressinstall/thread/e0ef4613-d90f-4eec-90db-41339ed31367/)

Or alternatively:

1. Reinstall your Visual C# 2010 Express
2. Upgrade to Visual C# 2012 Express

Answer (score 0):

Yes - you definitely need to include opencv_core242.dll in the bin/Debug folder (if that is where your output path is!) and in your project.

Keep in mind that the opencv_core242.dll is dependent upon other DLL's. Make sure you have them all included, as well, and that should solve your issue. If you can't find what DLL's are dependent upon opencv_core242.dll then try downloading Dependency Walker. It helps you find your dependencies in y building a hierarchical tree diagram of all dependent modules.

Good luck!!!